# Stop appending same element to the node

Tags: javascript

I am appending element on a node. I am stuck in  a situation that on every click event the same element get append to the parent.

How can I stop preventing the element to append again and again and add just once on the first click.

```js
   document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].onclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.innerHTML="error";
   document.getElementsByClassName("errors")[0].appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid black }
```

```html
<button class="btn" type="button">Click</button>
<div class="errors">Errors:</div>
```

Comment: I created you a snippet. Please make it show what you are descibing. If you are not cloning the DIV you will MOVE the div over and over again. The code currently does NOT add and add

Comment: You can check if that div already exist i.e. `document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].childNodes.forEach( (elem) => { if (elem === div) {console.log('element Already Exist')}})`

Comment: If you create the div outside the click, the SAME div is MOVED when you append, not ADDED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using the event, you could assign an empty function to the event.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].onclick = function(e) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    e.preventDefault();
    div.innerHTML = 'test';
    document.getElementsByClassName("errors")[0].appendChild(div);
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].onclick = function () {};
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">button</button>
<div class="errors"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a `div` (or *any other selector*) is already there or not.

```
var errorEl = document.getElementsByClassName("errors")[0];
var doesDivExist = !!errorEl.querySelector( "div" );
if ( !doesDivExist )
{
   errorEl.appendChild(div);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "error";
document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var errorEl = document.getElementsByClassName("errors")[0];
  var doesDivExist = !!errorEl.querySelector("div");
  if (!doesDivExist) {
    errorEl.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" type="button">Click</button>
<div class="errors">Errors:</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You an put a conditional in your click event... like this one, carefull this is asking if it has a a child, you might want to set a more specific conditional....

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].onclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (document.getElementsByClassName("errors")[0].firstChild) {
       document.getElementsByClassName("errors")[0].appendChild(div);
   }  
}
```